LineSegmentDetector takes too long to detect lines
I am trying to run OpenCV on an android application and want to use a LineSegment Detector to detect lines from the following table:

LineSegmentDetector lineSegmentDetector = Imgproc.createLineSegmentDetector(
  Imgproc.LSD_REFINE_ADV, 1, 0.35
);
    // This takes a lot of time
lineSegmentDetector.detect(table_img, lines);

However, using lsd.detect() takes a lot of time to run (takes more than 5 minutes before returning).
Any ideas on how it should be optimized?

Is the binary image the input for the LSD? LSD is strong when using it directly on the grayscale image. On a binarized image, better (faster) approaches might exists. If you want to stick to LSD, try to downscale the input image.

@Micka the image given above is the result of a canny edge detection performed on an initial image. This acts as the input for my LSD. Also, what do you mean by downscaling the input image? does it have to do with changing the height and width?

Yes. LSD uses a scale space to find lines. If you start with a smaller image it might have a lot less operations. Can you also try to apply LSD directly on the original image, instead of using canny edge detection?

context (there have been 2+ questions on the same task): https://stackoverflow.com/users/26358326/spongerooski?tab=questions
